# Objective C: no known instance method for selector

Tags: objective-c

Trying to call another static method in a file of static methods, although I get:
Tweak.xm:324:11: error: no known instance method for selector 'test'

```
static void rddhandler(id self2, SEL _cmd){
    [self test]; //
}

static void test() {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`test()` is not a method. It's a function. The syntax to call it is `test()`.